# How many 1's in last 4 days?

Tags: count, sum, informatica

[image]

I would like to count or sum how many 1's in last four days (1/1 to 1/4) for each name (A, B, C, D) in Informatica Developer. Advise please!!

Comment: can you pls add some example - like this is my input and this is the expected output?

Comment: Hi Koushik, thanks for your reply. I got 1 and 0 (please see above screenshot) through regex expression. Now I would like to count how many 1's are there. So my expected outcome would be the last column of the above screenshot 'How many 1's in last 4 dates'. I have count the data in excel, but would like to get an expression for informatica developer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply create an exp transformation and a new output port. Formula should be like this-

```
o_how_many_1s= day1 + day2+day3+day4
```

Now, you said, all the day* values can be wither 0 or 1, so adding them will give you count of 1s.

If you have null in these fields, then  you can use `IIF(isnull(day1),0,day1)` logic while adding.
If you have some numbers other than 0,1, then, then  you need to use something specific like this

```
o_how_many_1s= IIF(day1=1,1,0) + IIF(day2=1,1,0)+IIF(day3=1,1,0)+IIF(day4=1,1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Koushik. It worked. I had to change the data type as well.

Comment: I am happy that it worked :)